# $\phi_{n+1}(z)-\phi_n(z)$ converges uniformly then $\phi_n(z)$ converges uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

In Carleson/Gamelin *Complex dynamics* p. 31 it shown that an analytic function $f$ can be linearized near an attracting fixed point. Let $\phi_n(z)=\lambda^{-n}f^n(z)$. I have trouble understanding the uniform convergence of $\phi_n(z)$. Choosing $\delta>0$ such that $\rho<1$ they bound
$$|\phi_{n+1}(z)-\phi_n(z)|\leq \frac{\rho^nC|z|^2}{|\lambda|}$$ for $|z|\leq\delta$. Then they say $\phi_n(z)$ converges uniformly for $|z|<\delta$.

**I see that $\phi_{n+1}-\phi_n$ converges uniformly by the M-test. Does it follow that $\phi_n$ converges uniformly?**

To show $\phi_n(z)$ converges uniformly I would bound $|\phi_n(z)|$. I tried to use the triangle inequality and write $|\phi_n(z)-\phi(z)|\leq|\phi_n(z)-\phi_{n+1}(z)|+|\phi_{n+1}(z)-\phi(z)|$ but that doesn't help.

Comment: Weierstrass M-test does show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi_n(z)=\phi_1(z)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[\phi_{k+1}(z)-\phi_k(z)]$$ converges uniformly. Of course, this conclusion relies on the specific bound stated in OP. In general, uniform convergence of successive differences need not imply uniform convergence of the original sequence as we can see from the example $\phi_n(z)=\log n$.

Comment: Ah, a telescoping series, clever!